# NEXUS vs Global Entry for Canadian with US Permanent Residence

Tags: usa, canada, global-entry, nexus

I am a Canadian citizen with US Permanent Residence (Green Card). I am wondering whether I should apply for a NEXUS card or Global Entry. Since I understand that I can only have one or the other, I want to get the better one for my situation. **Note:** This question is specific to this nationality/immigration combination, as the suggestion may be different from the normal suggestion.

The standard suggestion for Americans is that they should choose the NEXUS card, because it is less expensive, and offers many of the same benefits.

However, I imagine there might be differences by virtue of the fact that I would not face the same scrutiny when crossing into Canada, as I am a citizen. Therefore, NEXUS might not be advantageous for me.

Is there a comparison of which would be better for my situation? I am specifically looking for information of what will be better both for crossing the US/Canada border and for flying to/from other international destinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should absolutely choose NEXUS over Global Entry, with one caveat below.

NEXUS includes all Global Entry benefits, plus adds some (for example, expedited airport security in Canada; ability to use NEXUS trusted traveler lanes entering Canada).  You will receive less scrutiny as a Canadian citizen when entering Canada, but NEXUS will save you time and often make you receive even less scrutiny than Canadian citizens normally receive.

You noted the lower fee already - NEXUS costs half of what Global Entry does.

The biggest disadvantage?  The interviews happen at sites in Canada (airports with US preclearance) or on or near the Canada-US border (the most distant is in Seattle).  That means you need to be at or near the border, or be willing to travel to it, for your interview.  Renewals sometimes require interviews (though less and less often now), so this could be a repeating issue.

Still, if you live near Canada or travel frequently enough to Canada, NEXUS is, to me, a no-brainer.  Just schedule interviews for times when you are already traveling to convenient places.  (No interview centre is near me, so I scheduled both of my interviews - new and renewal - during already-planned travel.)

Comment: I took your advice and got approved for Nexus. I traveled to Calgary this weekend to complete my interview. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As a US permanent resident (and Canadian citizen) the NEXUS card will give you all the Global Entry benefits, including TSA Pre✓. Citizens of third countries who are *Canadian* permanent residents don't get TSA Pre✓ with either NEXUS or Global Entry, but otherwise get all the rest of the benefits.

In addition, NEXUS will give you expedited clearance when you cross the US-Canada border by road, and when you arrive in Canada by air (at an [airport with NEXUS kiosks](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/nexus/airports-kiosks)). Global Entry itself will only give you expedited clearance when you arrive in the US by air.

There is a [comparison of trusted traveler programs](https://www.dhs.gov/trusted-traveler-programs) at the DHS web site, which gives a summary of each program and allows you to compare costs and benefits, and begin an application for any of the programs you wish.